# .net Application Updates

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm about to release a Beta version of an application and want to ensure that it can be updated remotely with users being notified in application that the update exists.  Ideally I would like to force the update if possable. I am currently using InstallShield LE that's packaged with VS2010 to build my install exe file.

My plan is the create a wcf web service that will deliver an XML manifect of all product versions.
What I'm not sure about is how to deliver the updates. The options I can think of are

1. Deliver a new installshield installer - The installer is quite a bit
   larger than the program so once the program is installed, sending
   out the complete installer seems overkill.
2. Send out just the msi
   file - I'm not sure how I go about creating an MSI installer within VS2010.
3. Download the new application files (An exe an approx 7 10 Dlls) and
   replace the current files with the new ones.

Does anyone have a thought as to which option would be best and how to implement it? Will I need some kind of code signing and check at the client end for security?

Thanks for any help.

EDIT-Should have mentioned that ClickOnce is not an option. Mainly because it's not customisable enough to fit in with our look and feel.  Also a few other issues with ClickOnce which I won't go into here.

Comment: You have tagged asp.net! Is it web app?

Comment: It has got a web component but it won't need updating so I've removed the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I faced a similar situation some years back, we were developing a product with several optional loosely coupled components. What we end up doing was when the application starts, it checks for our "UpdateService" and matches meta data.

If the application is not updated, we launch a separate process to update XML and bring down DLLs in byte array from our update service, which copies the XML and updated DLLs in respective folders.

That works for us at that time. Part of the reason was that client may upgrade features and we may need that to download additional DLLs.

However the first installation of the application was through installer (exe).

The challenge was that we have to write custom stuff along with proper management or version of the patches/assemblies. But it was good enough to be considered and satisfy product manager

Comment: Thanks Adil.  did you implement any kind of security like code signing to make sure the dlls being downloading were from you and that someone hadn't hacked your web server and placed viruses there instead?

Comment: Yes but I don't remember exactly. There were security checks at multiple level. For instance each client has encrypted licensed file and xml file for meta information. Plus the dlls were signed.

Comment: I went with a custom solution with DSE signing on the files downloaded.  Marking this answered as it's the closest to the solution I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

ClickOnce seems to be a good choice for you..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(v=vs.80).aspx

Best regards

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned in my question that ClickOnce isn't an option. I am using in my Dev environment but won't be suitable for production.

Comment: For me I'm using it for some early alpha testing,but I seriously worry about it in a production environment. When it goes wrong it can be a complete drain on support. I've seen cases where not only do you need to sort out your own clickonce app (Manually clearing up Reg entries, Files etc, to uninstall) but start looking at other clickonce apps installed on a system that may have nothing to do with you. I know these situations are rare but if you've got thousands of users installing an application it's not worth the risk IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to "replace" files in-place, unless you did Shadow Copying ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404279.aspx](http://bit.ly/KT2Vzp))  If you're not using ClickOnce you'll have to have some method to "check" in the application if there is an update.  I would imagine WCF is overkill for this; you could simply have a known URL to get a "version number" that could be compared to a version number in the app, and a known url to get the "latest" version...  Most apps simply download an MSI and ask the user to execute it.